# Identify repeating value with jquery

Tags: jquery, list, html-lists

Suppose I have a list like this

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery how can I identify when a value repeats.
My intention is to give the repeating values an alternative style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cycle through all the `<li>` objects, get their text and collect it into an object that you use as an index (for efficiency).  When done, see which items have more than one element with any given text and add a special class to them.  This solution uses an object to build an index for efficiency reasons.  The code works like this:

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 1</li>
</ul>​
```

Javascript with comments:

```
(function() {
    var index = {};
    $("#list li").each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        // if this text not in the index yet, create an array for it
        if (!(text in index)) {
            index[text] = [];
        }
        // add this item to the array
        index[text].push(this);
    });
    // cycle through the index and find each item that has more than one DOM element
    $.each(index, function() {
        // "this" will be an array of DOM nodes
        if (this.length > 1) {
            $(this.slice(1)).addClass("duplicates");
        }
    });
})();​
```

​Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zDhjD/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is one more thing I need to adjust. I only want to "addClass" to the dublicate value and not the original. Currently the class is added to original aswell.

Comment: @jamjam - I updated the code and the demo to not add the class to the first one found.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
   var val = $(this).text();  
   $("ul li").not(this).each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == val){
     $(this).addClass("mystyle");
    }
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tscRG/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
​$('ul > li')​.each(function(){
    var current = this;
    $('ul').find('li:contains(' + $(this).html() + ')').each(function(){
        if(current != this) {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/bbV9p/) on jsFiddle